# Principal value of 1/|x|

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

Can we define the Cauchy principal value of $\frac{1}{|x|}$? If yes, how does it act on a smooth function with a compact support? Is it defined as
$$\text{p.v.} \frac{1}{|x|}(\psi) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\epsilon, \epsilon]}\frac{\psi(x)}{|x|}dx $$ for $\psi(x) \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$?
It seems the above integral does not converge for $\psi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ if $\psi(0) \neq 0$. Do we have other ways to make $\frac{1}{|x|}$ a distribution on $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it *principal value* but rather *finite part*. It can be defined as the distributional derivative of $\operatorname{sign}(x)\ln|x|$:
$$
\langle \operatorname{fp}\frac{1}{|x|}, \psi(x) \rangle
:= \langle (\operatorname{sign}(x)\ln|x|)', \psi(x) \rangle
= - \langle \operatorname{sign}(x)\ln|x|, \psi'(x) \rangle
\\
= -\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \operatorname{sign}(x) \, \ln|x| \, \psi'(x) \, dx
\\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 
 \left( 
\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \ln|x| \, \psi'(x) \, dx
- \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \ln|x| \, \psi'(x) \, dx
 \right)
\\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( 
\left[ \ln|x| \, \psi(x) \right]_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} 
- \int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} \, \psi(x) \, dx
- \left[ \ln|x| \, \psi(x) \right]_{\epsilon}^{\infty}
+ \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, \psi(x) \, dx
\right)
\\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(
2 \psi(0) \ln|\epsilon|
+ \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{|x|} \, \psi(x) \, dx
\right)
.
$$

Comment: This is one possible distribution.  Another would be $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\psi(x)-\psi(0)\xi_{[-1,1]}(x)}{|x|}\,dx=\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{\psi(x)-\psi(0)}{|x|}\,dx+\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\psi(x)}{|x|}\,dx$$which is commonly used.

Comment: @MarkViola. I guess that they only differ by some multiple of $\delta.$

Comment: @MarkViola. Actually I find that your definition gives exactly the same distribution as mine.

Comment: Hi.  That is most curious.  Which distribution?  The one with $r=1$?

Comment: Ah.  Yes.  The one with $r=1$

Answer (score 1):

In Exercise $13$ of [THIS](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/), Terrance Tao asks the reader to show that a distributional interpretation of $1/|x|$ can be defined for any $r>0$ as the functional $\lambda_r$

$$\langle \phi, \lambda_r \rangle=\int_{|x|\le r}\frac{\psi(x)-\psi(0)}{|x|}\,dx+\int_{|x|\ge r}\frac{\psi(x)}{|x|}\,dx$$

It is interesting to note that the difference between two such functionals differs by a constant time the Dirac Delta distribution.  To see this note that

$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi, \lambda_r\rangle -\langle \psi, \lambda_s\rangle&=\phi(0)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\xi_{[-s,s]}(x)-\xi_{[-r,r]}(x)}{|x|}\,dx\\\\
&=2\phi(0)\log(s/r)
\end{align}$$

from which we see that in distribution we have

$$\lambda_r-\lambda_s=2\log(s/r)\delta(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Depending what *properties* we need the "regularization/extension" to have, the answer to the question can be "yes" or "no". Yes, as in the other answers, we can write formulas that extend integration-against-$1/|x|$ to all test functions (or Schwartz functions). On the other hand, if we require that the extension still be *even*, and *homogeneous* of the same degree (however we define it) as integration-against-$1/|x|$, then this is provably impossible.